# Adding 'exception' words to the rule of perl matching titles script

Tags: text-processing, perl

I have been using this perl script (thanks to Jeff Schaller) to match 3 or more words in the title fields  of two separate csv files as answered here:

[Matching 3 or more words from fields in separate csv files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283942/matching-3-or-more-words-from-fields-in-separate-csv-files?noredirect=1#comment494461_283942)

The script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

my @csv2 = ();
open CSV2, "<csv2" or die;
@csv2=<CSV2>;
close CSV2;

my %csv2hash = ();
for (@csv2) {
  chomp;
  my ($title) = $_ =~ /^.+?,\s*([^,]+?),/; #/ match the title 
  $csv2hash{$_} = $title;
}

open CSV1, "<csv1" or die;
while (<CSV1>) {
  chomp;
  my ($title) = $_ =~ /^.+?,\s*([^,]+?),/; #/ match the title 
  my @titlewords = split /\s+/, $title;    #/ get words
  my $desired = 3;
  my $matched = 0;
  foreach my $csv2 (keys %csv2hash) {
    my $count = 0;
    my $value = $csv2hash{$csv2};
    foreach my $word (@titlewords) {
      ++$count if $value =~ /\b$word\b/i;
      last if $count >= $desired;
    }
    if ($count >= $desired) {
      print "$csv2\n";
      ++$matched;
    }
  }
  print "$_\n" if $matched;
}
close CSV1;
```

I have since realised that I would like to ignore certain words between the titles and not class them as matching words. I've been using sed to remove them before the csv files are compared but this isn't ideal as I lose data in the process. How can I add words which would be considered as exceptions to this perl script? For example, let's say if I wanted the script to ignore the three separate words `and` `if` and `the` when matching the titles so that they would be exceptions to the rule.

Comment: the `perl` script in my answer below also answers your recently deleted question.  The `get_intersection` method from the `List::Compare` module eliminates duplicate entries (which is what you'd expect from set intersection), individual words are counted only once for each title.  This is one of the huge benefits of using existing library modules rather than writing your own - they usually include useful features that would take a lot of effort to implement yourself.  They also tend to have solved most or all of the common (and many not-so-common) problems related to the task at hand.

Comment: Hi cas, I tried your script yesterday, but I have one big problem unfortunately!  I'm running this on a synology box which has a basic form of linux. On running the script my machine didn't recognise Class::CSV so I tried installing it through CPAN and I couldn't get it to install despite a lot of effort! Unfortunately because of this i couldn't test out your answer I'm afraid :(

Comment: If you wanted to try it again, you could post a question about installing CPAN modules on a synology box, with examples of what you tried and what output & error messages you got.  List::Compare would also need to be installed.   btw does [this link](https://niebegeg.net/post/33886383878/compile-perl-modules-on-a-synology-nas-box/) help?

Comment: Thanks, i'll give that a go. My synology box switches on at 15:30 so I'll be able to try it remotely after that time. Cheers for your help.

Comment: Hi I tried your the recommendation in your link but no joy, i'm still getting 'make test had returned bad status, won't install without force'. I've added 'force' to the install command but it still doesn't end up installing. I'll keep searching for a solution though and maybe created a question on here at some point.

Comment: it's worth posting a question.  even if you don't end up using my script, not being able to use CPAN modules loses much of the value of `perl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the line

```
my @titlewords = split /\s+/, $title;    #/ get words
```

add the code to remove the words from the array:

```
my @new;
foreach my $t (@titlewords){
    push(@new, $t) if $t !~ /^(and|if|the)$/i;
}
@titlewords = @new;
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response, Is there anything I can add to ignore the upper/lower case? I've just tested and here is what I found- if the three words are in upper case in csv1 then there is no match so this works as I wanted. If the three words are in upper case in csv2 then it still matches them. If the three words are in upper case in both files it still matches them. How do I get it to ignore case completely ? cheers!

Comment: @nmh I should have thought of that. Simply add the `i` flag to the pattern. I edited my answer to show it.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to @meuh's answer, but instead of adding a `foreach` loop after the `split` line, you only need to add one line there, using either `perl`'s `grep` function or its `map` function:

```perl
@titlewords = grep (!/^(and|if|the)$/i, @titlewords);
```

or

```perl
@titlewords = map { /^(and|if|the)$/i ? () : $_ } @titlewords;
```

See `perldoc -f grep` and `perldoc -f map` for more details on these functions and the differences between them.  They are commonly used (especially `map`) in many `perl` scripts, so it is worth taking the time to understand what they do and learn how they work.

---

BTW, do **NOT** use `#!/usr/bin/env perl`.  Using `env` like that is bad enough with `python` and `ruby` scripts (where it is, unfortunately, the convention), but it is completely broken for `perl` scripts and definitely NOT the conventional way to run them.

`perl` has many command-line options which alter its behaviour in significant ways, depending on what kind of program you're trying to write.  Using `env` to run an interpreter like `perl` completely destroys the ability to pass command-line options to the interpreter (because `env` does not support it.  `env` wasn't even designed to be used for this purpose, doing so is just an ugly hack that takes advantage of a side-effect of `env`'s actual purpose - which is setting environment variables before running a program).

Use `#!/usr/bin/perl` instead (or whatever the path to your `perl` interpreter is).

---

Here's another perl script that does what you want - but this one uses the `Class::CSV` and `List::Compare` modules, as well as two Hashes-of-Arrays to compare the CSV files:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Class::CSV;
use List::Compare;

sub parse_csv($%) {
  my($filename,$tw) = @_;

  # exclude the following word list and the "empty word"
  my @exceptions = qw(and if the);
  my $exceptions = '^(\s*|' . join('|',@exceptions) . ')$';


  my $csv = Class::CSV->parse(
      filename => $filename,
      fields   => [qw/id title num1 num2/]
  );

  # build a hash-of-arrays (HoA), keyed by the CSV line. Each array
  # contains the individual words from each title for that line (except
  # for those matching $exceptions).  The words are all converted to
  # lowercase to enable case-insensitive matches.
  foreach my $line (@{$csv->lines()}) {

    # The following three lines are required because the input file has
    # fields separated by ', ' rather than just ',' which makes
    # Class::CSV interpret the numeric fields as strings.
    # It's easier/quicker to do this than to rewrite using Text::CSV.
    #
    # The final output will be properly-formed CSV, with only a comma as
    # field separator and quotes around the title string.
    my $key = join(',',$line->id,'"'.$line->title.'"',$line->num1,$line->num2);
    $key =~ s/([",])\s+/$1/g;   # trim whitespace immediately following " or ,
    $key =~ s/\s+([",])/$1/g;   # trim whitespace immediately preceding " or ,

    # If it wasn't for the not-quite-right CSV format, we could just use:
    #my $key = $line->string;

    push @{ $tw->{$key} }, grep (!/$exceptions/oi, split(/\s+/,$line->title));
  };
};

# two hashes to hold the titlewords HoAs
my %tw1=();
my %tw2=();

parse_csv('csv1',\%tw1);
parse_csv('csv2',\%tw2);

# now compare the HoAs
foreach my $k2 (sort keys %tw2) {
  my @matches = ();
  foreach my $k1 (sort keys %tw1) {
    my $lc = List::Compare->new('-u', \@{ $tw2{$k2} }, \@{ $tw1{$k1} });
    push @matches, $k1 if ($lc->get_intersection ge 3);
  };
  print join("\n",sort(@matches,$k2)),"\n\n" if (@matches);
};
```

Output:

```
11,"The Sun Still Shines in Reading",64312,464566
97,"Reading Still Shines",545464,16748967
```

Each group of matches is sorted and, even though the sample output doesn't show it (because there's only one group of matches), each group is printed as a separate paragraph (i.e. separated by a blank line)

BTW, if you don't want the double-quotes around the title fields, edit the `my $key=join(...)` line that adds them so that it doesn't.